# Applying a function elementwise

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I want to export an excel table full of integers then fill the empty spaces with 0, and then I want to turn this matrix into a sympy matrix so it can handle rational numbers properly. When I turn it into a sympy matrix it looks like the elements are not integers, and the inverse of the matrix are not rational numbers but numerical approximations.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify, implemented_function
from sympy import Function

problems_path = r'C:\Users\Lacika\Desktop\PHD\Kutatas\problems.xlsx'

problems_dict = pd.read_excel(problems_path, sheet_name=None, header=None)


for problem in problems_dict:
matrix_numpy = problems_dict[problem]
matrix_numpy = matrix_numpy.fillna(0).to_numpy()
det_orig = np.linalg.det(matrix_numpy)

diag = np.diag(matrix_numpy)
    #print(diag)
    #print(matrix_numpy)

matrix_sympy = sp.Matrix(matrix_numpy)
pretty_print(matrix_sympy)

matrix_sympy.applyfunc(floor)
pretty_print(matrix_sympy)
pretty_print(matrix_sympy**-1)
```

and the results:
[image]

I tried using `.applyfunc(floor)` but for some reason it doesn't do anything. I also tried with some lambda shenanigans but it didn't work.

Comment: If the excel/pandas part works, omit it and just give us a sample numpy array.  Can you convert the numpy array to int dtype?  'elementwise' are a lot easier in numpy.  Nothing involving a mix of packages like numpy and sympy is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use a prototype matrix with one element:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> m = Matrix([2.])
>>> m.applyfunc(floor)
Matrix([[2]])
>>> m
Matrix([[2.]])
```

The application of `floor` did something but *it returned something*, it did not act in place. If you want to work with the returned result interactively then do

```py
>>> m.appyfunc(floor)
Matrix([[2]])
>>> _**-1
Matrix([[1/2]])
```

else "catch" the result that is passed back to you

```py
>>> mi = m.applyfunc(floor)
>>> mi**-1
Matrix([[1/2]])
```

And it would probably be better to just `nsimplify` the matrix instead of applying `floor` (unless you are only working with integers, in which case `int` is sufficient instead of `floor`)

```py
>>> nsimplify(m, rational=True)
Matrix([[2]])
```